# Flatten nested array with key value pairs in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given an array like this:

```
[
    { id: 1, emailAddresses: ["bill@test.com", "bob@test.com"] },
    { id: 2, emailAddresses: ["sarah@test.com" },
    { id: 3, emailAddresses: ["jane@test.com", "laura@test.com", "paul@test.com"]
]
```

How could I use Javascript to reduce this to an array like this:

```
[
    { id: 1, emailAddress: "bill@test.com" },
    { id: 1, emailAddress: "bob@test.com" },
    { id: 2, emailAddress: "sarah@test.com" },
    { id: 3, emailAddress: "jane@test.com" },
    { id: 3, emailAddress: "laura@test.com" },
    { id: 3, emailAddress: "paul@test.com" }
 ]
```

I've read about the functions `reduce`, `flat`, `map` and so on and read lots of the questions on SO about using them but I can't find anything that's asking quite the same as this and I can't get my head around using those functions to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```js
const input = [
    { id: 1, emailAddresses: ["bill@test.com", "bob@test.com"] },
    { id: 2, emailAddresses: ["sarah@test.com"] },
    { id: 3, emailAddresses: ["jane@test.com", "laura@test.com", "paul@test.com"] }
]

const output = input.flatMap(o => 
    o.emailAddresses.map(e => ({ id: o.id, emailAddress: e }) )
)

console.log(output)
```

If `flatMap` is not supported, you could use a nested [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop:

```js
const input = [{id:1,emailAddresses:["bill@test.com","bob@test.com"]},{id:2,emailAddresses:["sarah@test.com"]},{id:3,emailAddresses:["jane@test.com","laura@test.com","paul@test.com"]}];
const output = []

for (const { id, emailAddresses } of input)
  for (const emailAddress of emailAddresses)
    output.push({ id, emailAddress })

console.log(output)
```

Comment: It's a shame `flatMap` isn't more widely supported at the moment, that is the cleanest looking of all the solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Array.prototype.reduce` to go over each object in the array and take into consideration the multiple values in the `emailAddress` property array and create *separate* object for each one and finally *accumulate* the new objects in the new array (`r`):

```js
const data = [
    { id: 1, emailAddresses: ["bill@test.com", "bob@test.com"] },
    { id: 2, emailAddresses: ["sarah@test.com"] },
    { id: 3, emailAddresses: ["jane@test.com", "laura@test.com", "paul@test.com"]}
]
const flat = data.reduce((r, e) => {
  e.emailAddresses.forEach((obj) => r.push({id: e.id, emailAddresses : obj }));
  return r;
}, []);
console.log(flat);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can map over your data and then use reduce to flatten the resulting array:

```
const result = data
  .map(datum => {
    return datum.emailAddresses.map(emailAddress => {
      return { id: datum.id, emailAddress };
    });
  })
  .reduce((result, current) => {
    return [...result, ...current];
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use reduce and map

```js
const data = [
    { id: 1, emailAddresses: ["bill@test.com", "bob@test.com"] },
    { id: 2, emailAddresses: ["sarah@test.com"] },
    { id: 3, emailAddresses: ["jane@test.com", "laura@test.com", "paul@test.com"]}
]

const flat = (toFlatten) => 
  toFlatten.reduce((r,c)=> {
    r.push(...c.emailAddresses.map(email=>({id: c.id, emailAddress: email})))
    return r
  }, [])

console.log(flat(data))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that doesn't use any array prototype but does, instead, take advantage of function generators.

The script below iterates the array, acquire all keys of the element except `emailAddresses`, which is handled separately, and for each email address it yields an object filled with the single email address and the rest of the data.

This solution iterate the original array only once.

Because it uses function generators, this solution is widely supported, it just won't work on IE due it's lack of support for function generators, despite babel or TSC can easily add compatibility to that.

```js
const input = [
    { id: 1, emailAddresses: ["bill@test.com", "bob@test.com"] },
    { id: 2, emailAddresses: ["sarah@test.com"] },
    { id: 3, emailAddresses: ["jane@test.com", "laura@test.com", "paul@test.com"] }
];

function* flattenEmailAddresses(arr) {
  for (var {emailAddresses, ...keys} of arr) {
    for (var emailAddress of emailAddresses) yield {...keys, emailAddress};
  }
}

console.log([...flattenEmailAddresses(input)]);
```