# Flatten nested array key value pairs without specifying each key in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Given an array like this:

```js
[
    { force_x: [1, 2, 3], force_y: [0.3, 0.4, 0.5] },
    { force_x: [4, 5, 6], force_y: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0] },
    { motion_x: [0.7, 0.7, 0.7] }
]
```

How could I use Javascript to reduce this to an array like this **without** specifying any keys:

```js
[
    { force_x: 1, force_y: 0.3 },
    { force_x: 2, force_y: 0.4 },
    { force_x: 3, force_y: 0.5 },
    { force_x: 4, force_y: 0.0 },
    { force_x: 5, force_y: 0.0 },
    { force_x: 6, force_y: 0.0 },
    { motion_x: 0.7 },
    { motion_x: 0.7 },
    { motion_x: 0.7 }
 ]
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57416425/flatten-nested-array-with-key-value-pairs-in-javascript?newreg=818fe64d52eb4b9083d8cbdcb2dabbf9) could work but I don't want to specify the key name, I want it to do it for every keys automatically.

```js
const output = input.flatMap(o => 
    o.emailAddresses.map(e => ({force_x: e }) )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get all the key value pairs and work with that.

```js
let arr=[{force_x:[1,2,3],force_y:[.3,.4,.5]},{force_x:[4,5,6],force_y:[0,0,0]},{motion_x:[.7,.7,.7]}];
let res = arr.flatMap(x => {
  const entries = Object.entries(x);
  return entries[0][1].map((_, i) => Object.fromEntries(
    entries.map(([k, v]) => [k, v[i]])));
});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much. Coming from c++ land, so this is all black magic to me :)

Comment: this works well as long as the number of items per array is the same for all keys. A preferred solution would not create keys for non-existing array items. For example, change `force_x:[1,2,3]` to `force_x:[1]`